# Books/reviews/papers on recommending groups of items?

Tags: recommender-system, books

Looking for books (chapters?)/reviews/papers on the task of recommending a few (possibly non-independent) items.

**Example**: office supply shop recommending a person a **pre-compiled package of items** of different kind (pens/pencils/erasers/paper/...) based on one's and other users purchases and views. The total cost of the package may be limited; other constraints could be introduced as well.

Any hints?

Thanks in advance.